# How to retrieve value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am returning a json as shown below,

```
{
    "entities": {
        "permissions": {
            "77de5140-9e1f-48b6-87a5-c80f12cd66d9": {
                "id": "77de5140-9e1f-48b6-87a5-c80f12cd66d9",
                "role": "ADMIN",
                "permissions": null,
                "canAccessAllAccounts": true,
                "allowedAccounts": null,
                "createdAt": "2022-01-30T18:20:46.901Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-01-30T18:20:46.901Z",
                "deletedAt": null
            }
        },
        "users": {
            "9bba4c96-781b-4012-9a48-071c1cb5ec24": {
                "id": "9bba4c96-781b-4012-9a48-071c1cb5ec24",
                "username": "246e6555eb16e3c8@ator.com",
                "activeAccountId": "a979189d-6bef-41f9-b224-892fbeb0955b",
                "enterpriseId": "9a69bba9-ed35-4589-8784-6b0e256bd7a0",
                "permissionId": "77de5140-9e1f-48b6-87a5-c80f12cd66d9",
                "firstName": "a48d1eb7270bb404",
                "lastName": "e0aaa6d09e19",
                "avatarUrl": null,
                "sendBookingRequestEmail": true,
                "isSSO": false,
                "createdAt": "2022-01-30T18:20:46.999Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-01-30T18:20:46.999Z",
                "deletedAt": null,
                "permission": "77de5140-9e1f-48b6-87a5-c80f12cd66d9"
            }
        }
    },
    "result": "9bba4c96-781b-4012-9a48-071c1cb5ec24"
}
```

I am trying to get `permissionsid` value (it is occurred three places in the JSON), also forgot to mention in the original comment that these alphnumeric values in `permissionid` and `userid` are dynamics

When I am using the following, I am getting `undefined`

```
var res = JSON.stringify(response.body);
var userResponseParser = JSON.parse(res);
var permission_id = userResponseParser['permissionId'];
```

When I am using the following, I am getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

```
var res = JSON.stringify(response.body);
var userResponseParser = JSON.parse(res);
var permission_id = userResponseParser.entities.permissions[0].id;
```

When I am using the following, I am getting `undefined`

```
var res = JSON.stringify(response.body);
var userResponseParser = JSON.parse(res);
var permission_id = userResponseParser.entities.permissions[0];
```

When I am using the following, I am getting `[object%20Object]`

```
var res = JSON.stringify(response.body);
var userResponseParser = JSON.parse(res);
var permission_id = userResponseParser.entities.permissions;
```

What I am missing here, couldn't find same kind of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why stringify and parse?

Anyway, it is more complex than you think

```js
const obj = JSON.parse(str)

console.log(Object.values(obj.entities.users)[0].permissionId)
```

```html
<script>
const str = `{
    "entities": {
        "permissions": {
            "77de5140-9e1f-48b6-87a5-c80f12cd66d9": {
                "id": "77de5140-9e1f-48b6-87a5-c80f12cd66d9",
                "role": "ADMIN",
                "permissions": null,
                "canAccessAllAccounts": true,
                "allowedAccounts": null,
                "createdAt": "2022-01-30T18:20:46.901Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-01-30T18:20:46.901Z",
                "deletedAt": null
            }
        },
        "users": {
            "9bba4c96-781b-4012-9a48-071c1cb5ec24": {
                "id": "9bba4c96-781b-4012-9a48-071c1cb5ec24",
                "username": "246e6555eb16e3c8@ator.com",
                "activeAccountId": "a979189d-6bef-41f9-b224-892fbeb0955b",
                "enterpriseId": "9a69bba9-ed35-4589-8784-6b0e256bd7a0",
                "permissionId": "77de5140-9e1f-48b6-87a5-c80f12cd66d9",
                "firstName": "a48d1eb7270bb404",
                "lastName": "e0aaa6d09e19",
                "avatarUrl": null,
                "sendBookingRequestEmail": true,
                "isSSO": false,
                "createdAt": "2022-01-30T18:20:46.999Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-01-30T18:20:46.999Z",
                "deletedAt": null,
                "permission": "77de5140-9e1f-48b6-87a5-c80f12cd66d9"
            }
        }
    },
    "result": "9bba4c96-781b-4012-9a48-071c1cb5ec24"
}`</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see only 2 places, but in any cases remove this from your code

```
var res = JSON.stringify(response.body);
var userResponseParser = JSON.parse(res);
```

since your response data is parced already automatically

Since you can have several permissions or users , you can not get your data just using [0] or [1] since you don' t know how many users can be in the response. So try this code ( it was tested and working properly)

```
var permissionIds=[];
 Object.values(response.entities.permissions).forEach(element => {
   permissionIds.push(element.id)
 }); 

var userIds=[];
 Object.values(response.entities.users).forEach(element => {
   userIds.push(element.id)
 });
```

Comment: These values are `77de5140-9e1f-48b6-87a5-c80f12cd66d9` and `9bba4c96-781b-4012-9a48-071c1cb5ec24` are dynamic

Comment: @JyotiPrakashMallick You have to update your question then, since it affects the result.